# Negative radial coordinates in polar plots

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

In polar plots $r=f(\theta)$, should a negative radial coordinate *always* be reflected? Even if $f(\theta+\pi)\neq-f(\theta)$? If $f$ does not involve any trigonometric functions?

For instance, is this correct?
[image: negative-radial-coords-ignored]

Or is this correct?
[image: negative-radial-coords-reflected]

##### My Argument

I think the first (where negative radial coordinates are ignored) is correct.

Our function is $f(\theta)=1-2\sin\theta$. Consider the point $(-1,\pi/2)$, which satisfies $r=f(\theta)$. The reflection rule tells us to transform it to $(1, 3\pi/2)$ and plot it. However, $f$ does not have the reflection property: in general, $f(\theta+\pi)\neq-f(\theta)$. Naturally, the transformed point does not satisfy $r=f(\theta)$. Why, then, should we plot it?

In other words, I think we should plot reflected points if and only if $f(\theta+\pi)\neq-f(\theta)$. This also makes sense if we consider non-trigonometric functions, like $f(\theta)=\theta-\pi$. (They also do not exhibit a sign-flip when rotated by $\pi$.) Is this intuition wrong?

##### Other Answers

Most demonstrations I have seen conveniently use simple functions with which a strong case is made for reflection. So, I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer to this.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1390608) seems to imply that we always reflect (since the statement about reflecting is made without reference to any function). On the other hand, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1737911) makes a case for not reflecting. I agree, but not for the same reasons (the author says that reflecting would make that particular function non-bijective).

[Here's another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3074020) that suggests reflecting without mentioning any specific functions. [And another](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4056223) [and another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783032) [and another](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2110523) (but the last two are justified, because the question wasn't asked in context of plots or functions).

Comment: Ignoring negative $r$ values in a polar graph is like ignoring negative $y$ values in a Cartesian graph.

Answer (score 1):

What should the graph of $$r=-\lvert\theta\rvert$$
look like? Taking the approach of omitting negative $r$ -- nothing, a blank plot. Taking the approach of reflecting the points, we have a spiral that shows symmetry with $r=\theta$.$^*$ Of the two of these, I think preserving the intuition that negating a result produces some kind of reflection should win out.

Nor does excluding negative $r$ solve the problem you are trying to fix. Imagine a graph of $r=\theta$ from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=6\pi$. Reading from points on the curve alone, it looks as if the points $(2\pi, 0)$, $(4\pi, 0)$ and $(6\pi, 0)$ are solutions to $r=\theta$. They are not, of course. What is actually happening is that, holding $r$ constant, $(r, \theta+2\pi k)$ names the same point for any integer choice of $k$. Points in polar form just aren't unique in the way points on the Cartesian plane are, and a little bit more inference from the viewer is required to figure out which integer multiple of $\theta$ is intended to be associated to which $r$. And once you accept you have to do *that* inferential work, what additional work are you saving yourself from doing by insisting that $r$ stay positive?

Answer (score 0):

@Blue:

> Ignoring negative $r$ values in a polar graph is like ignoring negative $y$ values in a Cartesian graph.

That's a weak analogy: ignoring a Cartesian graph's negative $y$ values artificially leaves its lower half permanently blank, whereas ignoring a polar graph's negative $r$ values neither is arbitrary ($r$ after all being a distance function) nor guarantees any part of it to be permanently unfilled.

---

> ##### My Arguments
>
> I think the first (where negative radial coordinates are ignored) is correct.

I prefer this too. (Note that in this case, every polar graph with an interval domain of length at most $2\pi$ has no "inner loop".)

Alternatively, we can allow $r$ to be negative and define the equivalence $$(r,\theta)\equiv(-r,\theta+\pi).\tag1$$

> I think we should plot reflected points if and only if $f(\theta+\pi)\neq-f(\theta).$

This contradicts the rest of your argument; I think you mean instead that we should plot reflected points iff $f(\theta+\pi)\equiv-f(\theta).$ But this is as good as saying that we should never *need* to plot reflected points:

> Our function is $f(\theta)=1-2\sin\theta$. Consider the point
> $(-1,\pi/2)$, which satisfies $r=f(\theta)$. The reflection rule tells
> us to transform it to $(1,3\pi/2)$ and plot it. However, $f$ does not
> have the reflection property: in general,
> $f(\theta+\pi)\neq-f(\theta).$ Naturally, the transformed point does
> not satisfy $r=f(\theta)$. Why, then, should we plot it?

If indeed $f(\theta+\pi)\equiv-f(\theta),$ then definition $(1)$ would be redundant. That definition (for polar graphing/plotting) was introduced precisely because in general, $f(\theta+\pi)\not\equiv-f(\theta).$